# Problems with route calculate

Tags: routes

I use routing v8 api. I create route calculations for:

```
    avoid[features]=dirtRoad
    transportMode=truck
    vehicle[grossWeight]=39999
```

I want that car to go by route no 1 near too Fagaras city in Romania.  As I know this is a good route for that kind of car. but your system
leads through routes 104A and 104C.

Additionally, even if I add one or more via with latLng from route no 1, according to v8 response truck should turn back and go again go by routes 104A and 104B.

Could you explain to me, why is that? Why does this route part is seems to be banned by v8?

I added some screenschots with this part of route:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Noone answer? I think it's really strange behavior.